# Xslt copy element to existing or create new if not exists

Tags: xslt

Pretty new to xml transformations and i'm stuck at (might be for you) pretty easy task.
Let's suggest we have source:

```
<root>
  <someValue>123</someValue>
</root>
```

It should be transformed into:

```
<root>
 <additional>
   <someValue>123</someValue>
 </additional>
</root>
```

But if we have this as a source:

```
<root>
 <additional>
  <b>something</b>
 </additional>
 <someValue>123</someValue>
</root>
```

we should move **someValue** to existing **additional**, i.e.:

```
<root>
 <additional>
  <b>something</b>
  <someValue>123</someValue>
 </additional>     
</root>
```

Keep in mind that there can be other elements at **a** level with same behavior (moved under **additional**).
Well, working example is much appreciated, but if it is accompanied by small description of how it works that would be fantastic (i prefer be tought to fish, rather than just being fed with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to add a `additional` wrapper as a child of `root`, and remove the existing `additional` wrapper - so its children move up to become children of `root` (or rather children of the added `additional` wrapper):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <additional>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </additional>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="additional">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will try, but at first glance - wont it double **additional** under **root**?

Comment: No. Why should it?

Comment: Thanks man, though not entirely wanted result but very close to it and you gave me a lot of things to think of and understand.

Comment: In what way does the result differ from the one shown in your question?

Comment: Well if I correctly reproduce, nodes which already was under **<additional>** in source (in case we already have **additional** from the beginning) go to root. But nevermind, I already got the idea.

Comment: `<b>something</b>` already was under `additional` in source. `<b>something</b>` remains under `additional` in the output: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfk

Answer (score 1):

> Keep in mind that there can be other elements at `a` level with same
>   behavior (moved under `additional`).

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root[additional|someValue]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <additional>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="additional/*|someValue"/>
            </additional>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::additional|self::someValue)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <additional>
        <b>something</b>
    </additional>
    <someValue>123</someValue>
    <anotherValue>keep</anotherValue>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <additional>
        <b>something</b>
        <someValue>123</someValue>
    </additional>
    <anotherValue>keep</anotherValue>
</root>
```

**Do note**: just one rule to override the identity transformation. Only process `root` meeting the conditions (`someValue` or `additional` childs). Copying `root`, applying templates to attributes (to further process), wrapping with an `additional` element the result of applying templates to `additional`'s childs and `root`'s `someValue` childs. Finally, applying templates to `root`'s childs, which are not `additional` nor `someValue`.

Comment: Thanks, I like it, the idea behind  is much like  the same, but it's quite laconic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/additional"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <additional>
            <xsl:copy-of select="someValue"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="additional/*"/>
        </additional>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here we strip original **additional** and then create it from scratch copying there needed **someValue** and original content from source (**additional/***)

Comment: If you're copying everything explicitly, then you don't need the *identity transform* template. But this does not meet your request to handle other elements that might be present.

Comment: I might be not understanding something, but I have more of unrelated stuff under root and it should be copied too, so isn't  identity transformation used for it purpose? But I clearly forgot to call <xsl:apply-templates/> before closing template for root. Or before </xsl:copy> ?

Comment: Yes, the way you have it now, the identity transform template will never be applied. And if you use it, why not use it **instead** of `xsl:copy-of`? That way you will eventually get to what I did in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use for version **xslt 2.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except someValue"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="additional">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::someValue"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not provide the expected result in the first case: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYin